# SQL query with joins and optional matching

Tags: mysql

I was programming a mapper to get info out of my database.

Here is the database:

- **spel( id, naam)**
- **spelbord(id, spel_id, level)**

  fk spel_id --> id in spel
- **veld(spelbord_id, posX, posY, veldNr, isTarget, Toegang)**

  fk spelbord_id --> id in spelbord
- **entiteit(spelbord_id, posX, posY, entiteitNr)**

  fk spelbord_id --> spelbord_id in veld

  fk posX --> posX in veld

  fk posY --> posY in veld

So I would like my query to give me:
the posX, posY, veldNr, Toegang, isTarget (and entiteitnr if it exists) of each veld.

For example:

```
1, 2, 1, true, false, 1
```

(there is an entiteit on this veld), or

```
1, 3, 1, true, false, null
```

(there is no entiteit on this veld).

This is my query but it doesn't seem to work

```
select v.posX, v.posY, v.veldNR, v.toegang, v.isTarget, i.EntiteitNr 
from spel as s
join spelbord as sb ON sb.Spel_ID = s.ID 
join veld v ON sb.id = v.Spelbord_id 
join entiteit i ON v.PosX = i.veld_PosX AND v.PosY = i.veld_PosY 
order by posX,posY
```

With this query I'm only getting the output where there is indeed an entiteit to connect with it.

What do I need to change to get the rows where there is no entiteit to match?

Comment: Use `left join` instead of `inner join`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is close; you need to add one word, LEFT, to the join between Enteitit and the other tables.  It also looks as though you don't need to use Spel or Spelbord at all for the data you need to select:

```
SELECT v.posX, v.posY, v.veldNR, v.toegang, v.isTarget, i.EntiteitNr
  FROM veld AS v
  LEFT JOIN entiteit AS i ON v.PosX = i.veld_PosX AND v.PosY = i.veld_PosY
 ORDER BY posX, posY
```

The presence/absence of Spel and Spelbord should not affect the result.  If they do make a difference, then you can certainly add them back, but it is unlikely to be a problem unless the ID columns in Spel and Spelbord are not primary keys.  (You documented the foreign keys; that's good.  It would be good to document the candidate keys too.)